# Failed assertion: line 116 pos 14: 'path.isNotEmpty': a document path must be a non-empty string

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

app type: Chat App

here is the code for the MessageScreen  ->

I am trying to upload message ID with some informations that shown below but whenever i try to write something on the chat screen, this ERROR pops up -

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:cloud_firestore/src/collection_reference.dart': Failed assertion: line 116 pos 14: 'path.isNotEmpty': a document path must be a non-empty string

```
        class MessageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
        final String username;
        String? userphotourl;
        MessageScreen({required String this.username, String? this.userphotourl});
      
        @override
        State<MessageScreen> createState() => _MessageScreenState();
      }
      
      class _MessageScreenState extends State<MessageScreen> {
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
        FirebaseFirestore FireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
        TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
        String chatRoomID = "";
        String messageID = "";
        var Email;
        var profilePicUrl;
        var usersStream;
        // var username;
      
        dashboard_screen dashboard = dashboard_screen();
      
        getMyInfo() {
          profilePicUrl = auth.currentUser?.photoURL;
          Email = auth.currentUser?.email;
        }
      
        updateLastMesageSend(String chatroomId, dynamic lastMessageInfoMap) {
          return FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("chatRooms")
              .doc(chatroomId)
              .update(lastMessageInfoMap);
        }
      
        Future addMessagetoDB(
            String chatroomID, String messageID, dynamic messageInfoMap) async {
          return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('chatRooms')
              .doc(chatroomID)
              .collection('chat')
              .doc(messageID)
              .set(messageInfoMap);
        }
      
        getChatRoomidUsernames(String a, String b) {
          if (a.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0) > b.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0)) {
            return "$b\_$a";
          } else {
            return "$a\_$b";
          }
        }
      
        addMessage(bool sendClicked) {
          if (textEditingController.text != "") {
            String message = textEditingController.text;
            var lastMessageTs = DateTime.now();
      
            Map<String, dynamic> messageInfoMap = {
              "message": message,
              "sendBy": widget.username,
              "ts": lastMessageTs,
              "imgUrl": profilePicUrl
            };
      
            //messageId
            if (messageID == "") {
              messageID = randomAlphaNumeric(12);
            }
      
            addMessagetoDB(chatRoomID, messageID, messageInfoMap).then((value) {
              Map<String, dynamic> lastMessageInfoMap = {
                "lastMessage": message,
                "lastMessageSendTs": lastMessageTs,
                "lastMessageSendBy": widget.username,
              };
      
              updateLastMesageSend(chatRoomID, lastMessageInfoMap);
      
              if (sendClicked) {
                // remove the text in the message input field
                textEditingController.text = "";
                // make message id blank to get regenerated on next message send
                messageID = "";
              }
            });
          }
        }
```